# How can I use Scala 3 match types in Quotes (macro)?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros, scala-3

My application needs to use Compiler staging vs the normal macro entry points.  (Long discussion involving what is knowable at runtime and what isn't, but take it as a given here.)

The run fn(), per API spec, gives you Quotes and nothing more.  You do your work and produce an Expr.  I need TypeRepr[T] in my function but it won't let me create Type[T].  How can I create Type[T] in the function?

```scala
  def inTermsOf[T](className: String): RType[?] =
    import scala.quoted.staging.*
    given Compiler = Compiler.make(getClass.getClassLoader)

    val newRType = {
      val fn = (quotes: Quotes) ?=> {
        import quotes.reflect.*

        // Tried this too--same error
        implicit val tt = Type.of[T]

        val traitRepr = TypeRepr.of[T](using Type.of[T]))
        // ERROR: Reference to T within quotes requires a given scala.quoted.Type[T] in scope.

        //...more code...
      }
      run(fn)
    }
```